# Create separate 7z archives for each directory in the current directory and additionally parallelize through GNU Parallel

Tags: compression, gnu-parallel, 7z

I have about two hundred sub-directories located within a directory of interest:

```
$ ls backup
201302
201607
201608
201609
201610
201701
201702
201705
201801
201802
```

I want to create a 7z archive `xyz.7z` for each directory `xyz`:

```
cd $HOME/backup/
7z a "storage/nas/TBL/compressed_backups/$xyz.7z" "$xyz" -mmt=4
```

So in the end I will have these archives in `storage/nas/TBL/compressed_backups`:

```
201302.7z
201607.7z
201608.7z
201609.7z
201610.7z
201701.7z
201702.7z
201705.7z
201801.7z
201802.7z
```

Additionally I want to use `parallel` in order to process five directories at a time. (I have enough computing power for this purpose)

`parallel -j5 ::: 7z a "storage/nas/TBL/compressed_backups/$xyz.7z" "$xyz" -mmt=4`

How can I wrap this all up together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following approach:

```
ls backup | parallel -j5 7z a -mmt=4 "storage/nas/TBL/compressed_backups/{}.7z" {}
```

- `{}` - input line. This replacement string will be replaced by a full line read from the input source.

Comment: Fantastic. And perhaps using `ls -d */` would be a better option (instead of plain `ls`) to ensure that only directories are passed to `7z`.

Comment: @vivoru, I thought you have only directories in `backup`